# Play movie fragments in a loop, optionally in slow motion

Tags: video

I have video files, in which dance lecturers performs some variations. To learn these variations, it would be effective to play some video file with following features:

- create markers in a video for individual variations, for example: from 00:03 to 00:17 - Sombrero de Lucy, from 00:19 to 00:26 - Cuban Guapea, from 00:30 to 00:41 - Enchufala con Bikini
- play selected variation (fragment in a movie) in loop
- play selected variation in slow motion

Could you recommend me some video player (or video sequencer / editor) with these or similar features? It can be for Linux or Windows, at best for free.

Comment: Which operating system? Must it be free, or do you have a budget? The more information that you give us, the better equipped we are to help you.

Answer (score 1):

VLC media player will fit 2 out of 3 of your requirements free and portable
[(portable version link)](https://portableapps.com/apps/music_video/vlc_portable)

[image]

After clicking the loop for the end of the loop, the video now starts looping.
Click the loop button again to stop the looping.

For slow motion click Playback > Speed > Slower.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pretty good round up of the best open source (free, for all intents and purposes) NLEs (non-linear editors): http://wolfcrow.com/blog/a-quick-guide-to-the-5-best-open-source-video-editing-software/

Out of the five recommended, I recommend checking out Lightworks. Lightworks has a free version as well as a paid for version, so make sure you download the correct one. You can find the free version here: http://www.lwks.com/index.php?option=com_lwks&view=download&Itemid=206

Comment: On this site we prefer you to actually have used the software which you recommend (since the questioner probably knows how to google) and to explain how if meets each point of the questioner.

Answer (score 0):

[Kdenlive](https://kdenlive.org) should do the trick for you. It's a feature rich non linear video editor for Linux distros (preferably based on KDE). It's very simple to learn and has the ability to rename and put marks on clips, and have the slow motion effect. To make the loop that you want, I suggest to you to edit the video clip I'm a way that makes you happy with the result, and then copy and paste it in the timeline until you reach the result that you want.

Answer (score 0):

[Replayer](https://replayer.app) (I am the author) ticks all your boxes.

> Replayer is a free, cue-based media player for rehearsals with
> playback music. By the click of a button, Replayer starts to play at
> predefined times in the audio or video file.

[image: Replayer with a dance instruction video playing]

- Loads [local (and online) video files](https://replayer.app/en/documentation/loading-music)
- You can [set up cues](https://replayer.app/en/documentation/edit-new-track) (time markers) that the can be seeked
- The cues can be individually [looped](https://replayer.app/en/documentation/loop-modes)
- The playback speed can be changed (however this depends on the browser support)

Here is an [use case documentation for dancers, with a live example](https://replayer.app/en/documentation/use-cases/replayer-for-dancers).